# Turning off an in-app purchase?

Tags: iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

We currently have a live app that features episodic content in the App store.

We're re-working our pricing, and instead of offering individual episodes for purchase, we want to have it as simply an entire pack of episodes.

My question is this: If I set my old identifiers to NOT cleared for sale, would a user who previously purchased that content still be allowed access to it?  (Meaning if I query whether they've purchased it, will it return true)

I'm new to the in-app purchase side of apps, and I'm not entirely sure how that works.

Also, if I delete the identifier from iTunesConnect, what happens?  Should this even be done?

Thanks in advance for any insight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];`, Apple will return all completed transactions in a `SKPaymentQueue` which is a collection of transactions. The transaction will contain the the `payment` object. The `payment` object will contain the `productIdentifier`. This info is available despite your deletion. Thus you may honor past purchases that are no longer for purchase.

Here is some example code:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];

#pragma mark SKPayment Observer Delegate methods
- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
    NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %i", queue.transactions.count);
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
    {
        NSLog(@"tran for product: %@ of state: %i", [[transaction payment] productIdentifier], [transaction transactionState]);
        switch ([transaction transactionState])
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                NSLog(@"found restored transaction: %@ productIdentifier: %@", transaction.transactionIdentifier, transaction.payment.productIdentifier);
                [self yourRestoreProcessSelector:transaction];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Argh, I wish I had known of this capability a while ago.  I want to disable old IAPs on old versions of my app, but allow users on a new version of the app to restore their old purchases (and get an upgrade too).  On restore, my code (hacked up from old UrbanAirship sample code) somehow ignores transactions that are no longer cleared for sale, so restore is disabled along with sale. :(  Thanks for the wisdom, though!